# How to change speed in FuncAnimation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation

basically I am trying to have a sine wave be displayed by matplotlib and then when a certain x value is reached (block_start_pos) for the animation speed to change (slow down in this case). I understand that FuncAnimation repeatedly calls update_plot based on the given parameters but I was wondering if there was a way to change the interval mid animation. My code (mostly taken from a youtube video) is shown below. Thanks!

````
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk


x = np.arange(0, 10*np.pi, 0.01)

index_of_refraction = 10

index_of_refraction_lst = [1, 200, 3, 4, 5]

medium = 20*index_of_refraction

w = 1

y = np.cos(w*x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)

data_skip = 50

block_start_pos = 6*np.pi 

def init_func():
    ax.clear()
    plt.xlabel('pi')
    plt.ylabel('sin(pi)')
    plt.xlim((x[0], x[-1]))
    plt.ylim((-1, 1))


def update_plot(i):
    ax.plot(x[i:i+data_skip], y[i:i+data_skip], color='k')
    ax.scatter(x[i], y[i], marker='o', color='r')
    return medium_test(i)

def medium_test(i):
    if x[i] > block_start_pos:
        index_of_refraction = index_of_refraction_lst[1]
        medium = 20*index_of_refraction

        
medium = 20*index_of_refraction


anim = FuncAnimation(fig,
                     update_plot,
                     frames=np.arange(0, len(x), data_skip),
                     init_func=init_func,
                     interval=medium)

plt.show()
# anim.save('sine.mp4', dpi=150, fps = 30, writer='ffmpeg')```
````